# R Error (from NA's to 0): duplicate subscripts for column in Data Frame

Tags: r, function, dataframe, na

I looked at multiple answers on Stackoverflow, but I stil couldn't fix my problem. I made a function that works, but I added something and now it won't work anymore. I want to replace all NA's to 0, which seems simple to me.

This is my function, and I added `bframe[is.na(bframe)] <- 0`:

```
B <- function(frame1, frame2, column){
  bframe <- merge(frame 1, frame2, by = column, all = TRUE)
  bframe$result <- bframe$freq.x - bframe$freq.y
  bframe$percentage <- (bframe$result/bframe$freq.y)*100
  bframe[is.na(bframe)] <- 0
  return(bframe)
}

B(DT2_1, 2_1, "BurgS")
```

However, it gives this error: `Error in '[<-.data.frame'('* tmp *, thisvar, value = 0) : duplicate subscripts for columns`.

The error occurs because there are NAs and it cannot perform the calculations:

```
BurgS  freq.x  freq.y  result   percentage  percentageABS
1      9204    184042  -174838  -94.99897   94.99897 
2      150     3034    -2884    -95.05603   95.05603 
3      130     2602    -2472    -95.00384   95.00384 
98     NA      47      NA       NA          NA
```

Not every data frame has this structure, so I am looking for a solution that changes NA's in the **whole** data set. Can someone help me out?

Changed 26/6/2018: I stumbled up the solution myself. The code is as follows, so that the `NA` of `freq.x` is changed to 0 and still can be part of the calculations which the outcome is shown in the last three columns:

```
B <- function(frame1, frame2, column){
  bframe$freq.x[is.na(bframe$freq.x)] <- 0
  bframe <- merge(frame 1, frame2, by = column, all = TRUE)
  bframe$result <- bframe$freq.x - bframe$freq.y
  bframe$percentage <- (bframe$result/bframe$freq.y)*100
  return(bframe)
}

B(DT2_1, 2_1, "BurgS")
```

Comment: What is `Bdf` ?

Comment: Oh sorry, wrong variable. Bdf = bframe. I edited the question.

Comment: Your method for substituting the zeros looks fine. Can you provide some sample input data which recreates the error?

Comment: I changed the data in my question. The thing is if Freq.x is NA, then the other variables cannot be computed. While writing this, I got an epiphany and changed the code to: `bframe$freq.x[is.na(bframe$freq.x)] <- 0`, and placed this line before `bframe$result <- bframe$freq.x - bframe$freq.y`, so that if freq.x was already stated to be NA it was changed to zero before the calculations. Now the last three columns can also be computed. However, I though the answer was to change every NA to 0, it wasn't because the 0 of freq.x had to be part of the calculations.But thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error and found another solution.

instead of:

`bframe[is.na(bframe)] <- 0`

try adding a comma after the is.na function:

`bframe[is.na(bframe), ] <- 0`

This worked perfectly for me!

Comment: Helped me! That missing comma is a typo.